# Get all instances of an interface with Dagger Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt, koin

I'm migrating DI from Koin to Dagger Hilt. I have a custom interface with many implementations, and I want to inject all the instances in a useCase as a list.

For example:

```
@Singleton
class MyUseCaseImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val myInterfaces: List<MyInterface>,
) : MyUseCase {
    ...
}
```

When I used Koin, I would do:

```
single<MyUseCase> {
    MyUseCaseImpl(
        myInterfaces = getKoin().getAll(),
    )
}
```

How can I do the same with Hilt?

I've already binded each implementation with my interface like:

```
@Binds
abstract fun bindFirstMyInterfaceImpl(
    firstMyInterfaceImpl: FirstMyInterfaceImpl,
): MyInterface
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [multibindings](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/multibindings.html). Provide your dependencies with `@IntoSet` annotation

```
@Binds
@IntoSet
abstract fun bindFirstMyInterfaceImpl(
    impl: FirstMyInterfaceImpl1,
): MyInterface

@Binds
@IntoSet
abstract fun bindSecondMyInterfaceImpl(
    impl: SecondMyInterfaceImpl,
): MyInterface
```

But instead of `List` multibindings uses `Set` (or `Map`)

```
@Singleton
class MyUseCaseImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val myInterfaces: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards MyInterface>,
) : MyUseCase {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I get an error that  `java.util.Set<? extends MyInterface> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

Comment: @ZookKep try to use `Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards MyInterface>`